# Matching Everything That Does Not Contain Anything in an Array with Regex

Tags: regex

I have the following regex query I'm trying to use to exclude assets from being cached:

```
^((?!(\.css|\.js|\.|\.json|\.xml|\.svg|\.ico|\.png|\.mp3|\.jpg|\.svg|\.woff|\.woff2|\.eot|\.ttf|\/api\/play\/add|\/api\/favorite|\/Listen\/channel|getAccountInfo)).)*$
```

Except it doesn't match https://exampl.com/home for some reason. Does anyone know how I can fix this? Also, is there anyway I can make the Regex expression better?

Comment: Yes, thank you! I selected it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex contains a `|\.|` part (after `|\.js`). That alternative makes your regex fail the match with any string containing a dot. You need to remove that alternative:

```
^((?!(\.css|\.js|\.json|\.xml|\.svg|\.ico|\.png|\.mp3|\.jpg|\.svg|\.woff|\.woff2|\.eot|\.ttf|\/api\/play\/add|\/api\/favorite|\/Listen\/channel|getAccountInfo)).)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SOuUbV/1)